# How to "explore" group of servers?

Tags: database, linux, unix, networking, architecture

I need to check a group of servers (Unix, Linux) to know what kind of services, software (also version) are running there (check it once for a while and store it in database).
The idea is to have always fresh info about whole environment - its constantly changing. Perhaps you can suggest some solution that is already there?
Currently i am thinking about using Nagios or Cacti + plugins but I am not sure if this solution will be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios is a very powerful monitoring solution (the best for me) : Open source, Compatible with both linux & windows, reporting & notifications via emails/SMS, Nice interface, Many many plugins...etc I've already worked with & I was very satisfied.

Check Nico Largo's Forum for Install. If you are not familiar to linux command search for FAN : Fully Automated Nagios which is a .iso where nagios is already in.

If you have any trouble during install or configuration post your questions there : https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to poll for information on the system that can change dynamically, I would look at Check_MK.

It originally started as a plugin for Nagios that would poll a server for running services and generate the necessary configs for monitoring anything it discovered.  Since then, it has evolved into a complete monitoring solution that provides its own complete ui (still based on nagios core), so you are safe in running this if you are familiar with nagios already.

See the website: http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_monitoring_system.html

You may need to select that you wish to view the "English" perspective of the site on first visit.